# @google-cloud/pubsub TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of undefined

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-pubsub

Installed the google cloud pub sub following instructions from the following link,
https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/libraries

Imported that as the following,

```
const { PubSub } = require("@google-cloud/pubsub");
const projectId = "projectXYZ";

const pubSubClient = new PubSub({ projectId });

export async function publishMessage(topicName, data) {
  return await pubSubClient.topic(topicName).publish(JSON.stringify(data));
}
```

this leads to the following error,
[image]

Now, what I have observed is that the code below the import has no significance in this issue, since this error still appears even if I only import on the first line.
Am I missing something or required to install something more that just the package?
Any help is deeply appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Library maintainer here! I'm guessing from the stack trace that you're using webpack on your app? Right now we don't have webpack and rollup support - there are a few weird things like what you see above. Your code looks okay. We'd like to get webpack and similar tools working at some point for server-side usage, but it hasn't gone very high on the priority list just yet. I think the previous assumption was that people were trying to use it in a web browser, which we don't recommend for a number of reasons (most prominently, security concerns with GCP credentials). But I've been seeing a lot of issues with users trying to use webpack on the server side to make their Cloud Functions more compact, which seems pretty legit. I'll bring it up in our next team sync.

If you're *not* using webpack, then that sounds like something that might be filed over at [the issue tracker](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-pubsub/issues).

Comment: I'm using NextJS - my builds on cloud build used to work back in December 2022, but now releasing new work in Feb 2023 I'm getting this issue. Nothing else has changed, so is there some sort of borked patch update?